# Why is it that when I want to open minergate console version but it give me this error?

Tags: ubuntu, runtime-error, bitcoin

I've tried to install `Minergate console` version on `Ubuntu` and when I want to open it but the `Terminal` give me this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'spdlog::spdlog_ex'
>   what(): logger with name 'core' already exists
>   Aborted (core dumped).

Answer (score 5):

Having searched further for the answer I found that the issue resides with version 1.6 and later of the minergate software.

Uninstall* the version you currently have:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove minergate
```

Now download and install version 1.5 using the following commands:

```
curl -o minergate-cli.deb https://download.minergate.com/xfast-ubuntu-cli/1.5 && sudo dpkg -i minergate-cli.deb
```

Then run the software using the command:

```
minergate-cli --user <minergate user email here> --xmr 6
```

Note that the 6 should be changed to however many threads you want to run at the same time which will depend on what hardware you are running.

[edit] added the uninstall command

Comment: Is it okay to use an older version? Doesn't the mining/hashing algorithms change in the new version?

Comment: Thanks.. Uninstalling minergate v1.7 and reinstalling v1.5 works !!

Answer (score 0):

For people having the same issue, you certainly have another instance of Minergate installed on your system (probably the GUI version).
List, then remove the installed ones:

```
sudo dpkg -l |grep -i minergate
sudo apt remove minergate*
```